# Registry key edited but policy still disabled

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have a script that is setting a registry key but the local policy remain disabled.

I have tried issuing the gpupdate & gpupdate /force to no avail.

Powershell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "fResetBroken" -Value 1
```

Tried gpupdate & gpupdate /force

```
Invoke-Command -computer $line -script {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "MaxDisconnectionTime" -Value 900000
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "MaxIdleTime" -Value 1800000
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "fResetBroken" -Value 1
        #echo "Y" | gpupdate /force

        echo $line" Registry Key Successfuly Changed"   
    }
```

I want the registry key set to 1 = enabled and for the policy to change to enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It's a dword.  Surprise, there's an undocumented -type parameter for registry keys.

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services' fResetBroken 1 -Type Dword
```

Comment: gonna give this a try!

Comment: When i drill down the policy the end session when limit reached is still disabled... Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to reboot? How about that?